# elasticsearch match query used against a field array returns bad results

Tags: elasticsearch

I use this search query:

```
GET videosearch/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": "logs"
    }
  }
}
```

in order to return all documents that contain "logs" in the tags field.

Tags field has this mapping:

```
    "tags": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "english",
      "fields": {
        "verbatim": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
```

The query returns good results like this one:

```
{
    "_index": "videosearch",
    "_type": "videos",
    "_id": "10",
    "_score": 0.792282,
    "_source": {
      "id": "10",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDLtyLi6Ny8",
      "title": "#bbuzz: Radu Gheorghe JSON Logging with Elasticsearch",
      "uploaded_by": "newthinking communications",
      "upload_date": "2013-06-19",
      "views": 370,
      "likes": 0,
      "tags": [
        "elasticsearch",
        "logs",
        "logstash",
        "rsyslog",
        "json"
      ]
    }
  }
```

but also return bad results like this one:

```
{
    "_index": "videosearch",
    "_type": "videos",
    "_id": "15",
    "_score": 0.9054651,
    "_source": {
      "id": "15",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L1DjY90Whk",
      "title": "Tuning Solr for Logs, by Radu Gheorghe",
      "uploaded_by": "Lucidworks",
      "upload_date": "2015-01-07",
      "views": 280,
      "likes": 2,
      "tags": [
        "logging",
        "solr",
        "tuning",
        "performance"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I consider the last one a "bad" result because it does not contain the "logs" string in the tags field. Also I can notice that even if it is a "bad" result it has a greater score than "good" result: 0.9054651 vs 0.792282.

What is happening, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I read about analyzers, which are used by elasticsearch to break words into tokens.

English analyzer is using stemming in order to construct the tokens.
In the bellow example I will break some words into search tokens using the english analyzer:

```
GET _analyze?pretty
{
  "analyzer": "english",
  "text": ["hair dryer", "introduction", "stars", "Introspective", "fishing", "logging"]
}
```

This results in the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hair",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "dryer",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "introduct",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 23,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "star",
      "start_offset": 24,
      "end_offset": 29,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "introspect",
      "start_offset": 30,
      "end_offset": 43,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "fish",
      "start_offset": 44,
      "end_offset": 51,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "log",
      "start_offset": 52,
      "end_offset": 59,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

You can notice that the tokens are in fact the corresponding word stems for each word that is to be analyzed.

In conclusion the words *log*, *logs*, *logging* have the same word stem which is **log**, so all three of them are search results candidates.